# store exit code of grep in makefile variable

Tags: command-line, terminal, makefile

I'm using the shell function inside a makefile to do a grep search:

RESULT = $(shell grep find in)

Instead of storing the result of grep, can I store just the exit code? Alternatively, is the a way to check if RESULT is nonempty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `RESULT = $(shell COMMAND; $$?)`, explanation:

- `COMMAND` is the command you want to check the exit code for (`grep find in` from your example)
- `;` separates any two commands
- `$$?` gets parsed as `$?` by `make` and as such is passed to the shell, and:

  > [`$?` always expands to the status of the most recently executed foreground command or pipeline](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-how-to-determine-the-exit-status-of-linux-and-unix-command)

You can also use [FD redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) to get rid of `COMMAND`'s output.

Comment: I get `/bin/sh: 0: command not found`, so I just do `$(shell COMMAND; echo $$?)`

Answer (score 0):

You need 'grep' result redirect to /dev/null, and then print exit code:
`RESULT = $(shell grep find in >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; echo $$?)`

Comment: `&>/dev/null` is a nonstandard deprecated `bash` extension, don't use it